# Woocommerce search on product title with like in query

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to implement search on product name using followin query

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'product',
   'category' => array( 'Uncategorized' ),
   'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
   'paged' => $paged,
   'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_name',
            'value'   => 'new',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
)
```

So when i try to echoing the query it's giving me

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS rr_posts.ID FROM rr_posts INNER JOIN rr_postmeta ON ( rr_posts.ID = rr_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND (((rr_posts.post_title LIKE '{98de05f123e060606981f2829a3837e92e21cc65733761b8e300cc5aa370ea10}new{98de05f123e060606981f2829a3837e92e21cc65733761b8e300cc5aa370ea10}') OR (rr_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '{98de05f123e060606981f2829a3837e92e21cc65733761b8e300cc5aa370ea10}new{98de05f123e060606981f2829a3837e92e21cc65733761b8e300cc5aa370ea10}') OR (rr_posts.post_content LIKE '{98de05f123e060606981f2829a3837e92e21cc65733761b8e300cc5aa370ea10}new{98de05f123e060606981f2829a3837e92e21cc65733761b8e300cc5aa370ea10}'))) AND ( ( rr_postmeta.meta_key = '_name' AND rr_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{98de05f123e060606981f2829a3837e92e21cc65733761b8e300cc5aa370ea10}new{98de05f123e060606981f2829a3837e92e21cc65733761b8e300cc5aa370ea10}' ) ) AND ((rr_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (rr_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR rr_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR rr_posts.post_status = 'private'))) GROUP BY rr_posts.ID ORDER BY rr_posts.post_title LIKE '{98de05f123e060606981f2829a3837e92e21cc65733761b8e300cc5aa370ea10}new{98de05f123e060606981f2829a3837e92e21cc65733761b8e300cc5aa370ea10}' DESC, rr_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 2
```

Why it's changing the search value and what if i want to search `like %new%`